# Refactoring Azure Data Lake Gen2 file upload from frontend to backend

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have the following React/Typescript code to upload file to Azure Data Lake Gen2 storage directly from the frontend. It works great.

```
  const onHandleChange = (event: any) => {
    const file: File = event.currentTarget.files[0];
    instance
      .acquireTokenSilent({
        scopes: ['https://storage.azure.com/.default'],
        account: accounts[0] as AccountInfo,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        const header = new Headers();
        header.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${response.accessToken}`);
        const path = `https://${ACCOUNT}.dfs.core.windows.net/${FILESYSTEM}/${USERNAME}/${FILENAME}`;

        fetch(`${path}?resource=file`, {
          method: 'PUT',
          headers: header,
        })
          .then(() =>
            fetch(`${path}?action=append&position=0`, {
              method: 'PATCH',
              headers: header,
              body: file,
            })
          )
          .then(() =>
            fetch(`${path}?action=flush&position=${file.size}`, {
              method: 'PATCH',
              headers: header,
              body: '',
            })
          )
          .then((resp) => {
            console.log(resp);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Demo App</p>
      {isAuthenticated && (
        <form>
          <input type="file" id="fileField" onChange={onHandleChange}></input>
        </form>
      )}
      <UnauthenticatedTemplate>
        <button onClick={() => signInClickHandler(instance)}>Sign in</button>
      </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
    </div>
  );
```

I would like to refactor this code to place the call to Azure API in the Express backend. Below is what I have so far - it is essentially the sample code split between frontend and backend. I am able to successfully get as far as the last patch/flush call until I hit **"400 The uploaded data is not contiguous or the position query parameter value is not equal to the length of the file after appending the uploaded data."**

I have checked that the file size is correct at 805B for my test file and is correctly added to the `position=${size}` in the last patch/flush call. Could it be that the format of the file has changed after it was sent to the backend?

**In Frontend**

```
  const onHandleChange = (event: any) => {
    const file: File = event.currentTarget.files[0];
    instance
      .acquireTokenSilent({
        scopes: ['https://storage.azure.com/.default'],
        account: accounts[0] as AccountInfo,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        const data = await file.arrayBuffer();
        fetch("/file", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Authorization: response.accessToken,
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          },
          body: data,
      }).then((uploadResponse: Response | Promise<Response>) =>
          console.log(uploadResponse)
        );
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Demo App</p>
      {isAuthenticated && (
        <form>
          <input type="file" id="fileField" onChange={onHandleChange}></input>
        </form>
      )}
      <UnauthenticatedTemplate>
        <button onClick={() => signInClickHandler(instance)}>Sign in</button>
      </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
    </div>
  );
```

**In Express**

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  const accessToken = req.headers.authorization;
  const file = req.body;
  const size = req.headers['content-length'];
  const header = new fetch.Headers();
  header.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`);
  const path = `https://${ACCOUNT}.dfs.core.windows.net/${FILESYSTEM}/${USERNAME}/${FILENAME}`;

  fetch(`${path}?resource=file`, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: header,
  })
    .then(() =>
      fetch(`${path}?action=append&position=0`, {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: header,
        body: { ...file },
      })
    )
    .then(() =>
      fetch(`${path}?action=flush&position=${size}`, {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: header,
        body: '',
      })
    )
    .then((resp) => {
      console.log(resp);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
});
```

Comment: I am guessing reason your code is failing is because the data is sent as `multipart form data`. Can you try by converting your file object to an [array buffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer) and use that to upload the content.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I tried doing that; however, I still get the exact same behavior on the backend it seems. If I console.log the received data on the back end, it looks exact same whether it was sent as file object or as an array buffer: '����\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00`\x00`\x00\x00��\x00C\x00\x03\x02\x02\x03\x02\x02\x03\x03\x03\x03\x04\x03\x03\x04\x05\b\x05\x05\x04\x04 ....`

Do I need to change `Content-Type` in the header?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the updated code?